# .NET Parallel.ForEach possibly messes up NHibernate context session

Tags: asp.net, .net, nhibernate, parallel-processing

I have several report objects as follows : BaseReport, ChildReport1, ChildReport2, and ChildReport3. A report can implement IComplexParameterSupport interface. ChildReport1,2 and 3 all inherit from BaseReport.

My logic is as follows

1. Open NHibernate context using the SessionFactory
2. I use recursion to generate a tree from the report types to generate a sort of menu. This is from a Parent/Child hierarchy - calling the database several times, validating each time the report type and doing specific actions related to the report definitions.
3. Then After, I do checks if the report object is IComplexParameterSupport.

In some cases when I know that the report implements IComplexParameterSupport, when I do the casting, the report object stays null. It is like the context of NHibernate has been lost.

```
    if(report as IComplexParameterisedSupport != null)

    {
       // logic here
    }
```

This happens only when I previously use the Parallel.ForEach, i.e on STEP 2. I am using a Web Application on .NET 4.0. Does anyone have similar problems with parallelism and NHibernate context sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Does this mean that the session can be accessed at the same time by multiple threads?
If so, this is the problem, since NHibernate's Session is not thread safe.
See [NHibernate thread safety with session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629719/nhibernate-thread-safety-with-session)